# How to store SQL query result into data frame in R

Tags: r, mysql-connector

I want to store SQL query into data frame for visualization since it's difficult to drawing plots from SQL query result directly. below is my R code so far:

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user='root',
                 password='XXXXX',
                 dbname='Databasename',
                 port=3306)
dbListTables(mydb)

rs <- dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT XXX FROM XXX WHERE X = Y;") 
dbFetch(rs)
```

How can I store rs to a data frame using R? Obviously it can't be converted uisng the data.frame function directly.

Comment: You could use `dbGetQuery` and store it `rs <- dbGetQuery(mydb, "SELECT XXX FROM XXX WHERE X = Y;")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assign the `dbFetch` output to an object and then clear the results with `dbClearResult`

```
rs1 <- dbFetch(rs)
dbClearResult(rs)
```

Now, check

```
str(rs1)
```

---

Or instead of `dbSendQuery/dbFetch`, use `dbGetQuery`

```
rs <- dbGetQuery(mydb, "SELECT XXX FROM XXX WHERE X = Y;")
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE cyl = 4")
rs1 <- dbFetch(rs)
dbClearResult(rs)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: I got this error when using dbGetQuery "Warning message:
In .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  Decimal MySQL column 0 imported as numeric"

Comment: @SherlockLTS from your comment, it looks like a `Warning` and not `Error`